# SED shadow master boot record and linux md raid 1

Tags: linux, ssd, encryption, grub, raid-1

I'm contemplating this setup:

- Two SSDs with SED (self encrypting drive),
- in a software raid mirror,
- linux (or grub?) to unlock the two disks with one pwd from the Shadow Master Boot Record

I have already implemented a full disk encryption on sw raid where the resulting raid image is the encrypted luks container. I'm happy with this as it minimizes the unencrypted surface. It works great but has some drawbacks: First, I'm typing my password twice - once for grub and once for linux kernel. Second, the encryption key is probably floating around somewhere in kernel memory.

With SED I'd like to achieve the following: Keep the same password for both drives so both can be unlocked at once. Once unlocked, no more passwords are needed. No encryption keys in memory, they are contained/protected by the SED.

Has anyone done this or parts of it? Would you recommend this? What is your experience and procedure?

UPDATE: found that there's [Drive Trust Aliance](https://www.drivetrust.com/) working on [sedutil](https://github.com/Drive-Trust-Alliance/sedutil) with a nice pun on their website: "There Should Be No Encryption Backdoors, Only Front Doors"

Comment: If your drives have built-in self encryption, and your bios (uefi?) supports it, you should just enter the passphrase to the bios, and that's it for passphrases. Everything on the drive *should* be encrypted by the drive itself, you can skip LUKS & "full disk encryption" (and it's performance penalty) and forget about the kernel having the key. That's *if* you trust the drive to be secure

Comment: Thanks @Xen2050, but wouldn't I have to type the password for each drive then? I have some sophisticated password which takes time to type :o) Also consider higher raid configurations, type 3x, 6x...

Comment: Probably, two encrypted drives with two pssphrases, with LUKS or SED/BIOS would probably need each passphrase entered. Having an option to try the same password on all drives doesn't sound too secure. For just one passphrase entry, you could go with LUKS on top of the RAID/LVM, but that's more complex than just using built-in SED. The [cryptsetup FAQ](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/wikis/FrequentlyAskedQuestions) suggests using RAID as the "bottom" layer, with LUKS on top

Comment: Hi, bioses have funny quirks like limiting you pwd length or remembering the pwd for sleep or implementing the feature incorrectly or not at all. That's why the shadow MBR looks so appealing to me. You have a point with the same pwd on two drives, perhaps it could be dealt with having the pwd variants generated per drive using separate key files hashed with the single pwd. The keyfiles could be on a removable device adding a level of security. I have already a system running with cryptsetup luks on raid 1 and it works great as outline above, but I'd really like to exploit the SED feature :o)

Comment: I'll take care to find some trusted SED manufacturer, likely not from US? ;o)

Answer (score 0):

There's lots of ways for things to go wrong in encryption, I read of one SED drive that just stored the password on the drive basically in plaintext (more below).

Sleep & hibernate are troublesome for LUKS sometimes too.

I'm not sure what or where to find a good manufacturer, almost all drives may be made by 2 companies anyway, probably in asia (Samsung? Now WD?)

Looking up Samsung & hard drives, I found this neat list & graphic on Wikipedia [List of defunct hard disk manufacturers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_defunct_hard_disk_manufacturers)

[image]

[List of solid-state drive manufacturers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_solid-state_drive_manufacturers) shows almost 80... At least in 2013, the [5 Most Influential Enterprise Flash Storage Companies](http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/enterprise-flash-storage-ssd,2-644.html) were Intel, Micron Technology, Samsung, Sandisk, and Toshiba.

Anyway, the [Western Digital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Digital) page lead to this interesting article on Vice:

### [Some Popular 'Self Encrypting' Hard Drives Have Really Bad Encryption](http://motherboard.vice.com/read/some-popular-self-encrypting-hard-drives-have-really-bad-encryption)

- > "[D]ue to a tragicomedy of errors on the part of [Western Digital], the security of the drives is actually very weak.”
- > [T]he worst of the problems is how the encryption keys are generated. “[Western Digital] does it using the C rand() function, which is known not to be cryptographically secure,” he wrote. Rand() is a very simple command for returning a pseudo-random number, and is not up to the task of producing a suitably strong key for keeping data secure.
  >
  > On top of this, the key is seeded with the time it was created in a 32-bit format. “That means instead of requiring billions of years to crack, an attacker who steals your drive can guess the key in a short time using a single PC,”
- > After all that, it turns out that some models just store the password on the hard drive anyway. That means an attacker wouldn’t even need your password to break into the device.

After that, there is also the BIOS to think about, I haven't read that there are any serious security concerns with SED's there, yet. Maybe just sticking with a well tested software encryption, like LUKS, is safer (at least until more SED drives are tested & confirmed to be secure. If a SED drive were to let linux write & run it's own code on the drive, that would be nice...).

[Started as a comment but went a little too far]

Comment: :o) I gather, your answer is essentially: "Don't". That is an answer I would accept given the elaborate argument and evidence you presented. We'll give a chance to other participants and more digging as well for another while.

Comment: Here's another argument to support this answer - https://www.blackhat.com/docs/eu-15/materials/eu-15-Boteanu-Bypassing-Self-Encrypting-Drives-SED-In-Enterprise-Environments.pdf Manufacturers in general do not protect the drive against cable tampering. Since the decryption state is completely internal to SED, all these attacks are possible.

Comment: I'd use a SED, just not one of the vulnerable WD's, and one that can be unlocked from linux sounds good (may need a regular non-encrypted boot drive though). For especially sensitive data using LUKS &/or encrypted folders (like eCryptfs/EncFS), even on top of the SED, should really minimize any exploits in a single layer; more layers of security is generally *more better* ;-) The threat model is important to consider, hiding files from nosy kids is really different from a computer taken by professional thieves or a government.